# MatTableDataSource has not been processed in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular material. When i tried to bind the tablesource to mat-table I'm getting the compile error as like below:
"node_modules/@angular/material/table/table-data-source.d.ts:25:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

```
This likely means that the library (@angular/material/table) which declares MatTableDataSource has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy."
```

My code in component.html :

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="emplist">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Emp_Id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Emp_Id </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">  </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
   
    <!-- For Title -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Emp_Name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Emp_Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">  </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
   
    <!-- For Completion Status -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Emp_Gender">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>  Emp_Gender </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">  </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
   
    <!-- For Completion Status -->
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
    <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="EditEmployee(data.Emp_Id)">Edit</button>
    <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="DeleteEmployee(data.Emp_Id)">Delete</button>
    </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
   
    <!-- <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row> -->
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
   </mat-table>
```

My service calling method in componet.ts

```
   GetEmployeesData(){
    this.serviceref.GetEmployees().subscribe(
      (res : any) =>
      {
        this.emplist =  res.data;
        console.log(this.emplist);
      },
      error =>{
        console.log(error);
        alert(error);
      }
      )}
```

Unable to find why the compiler is throwing the error.

Comment: Removing node_modules and running npm i again solved this for me.

Comment: I'm newbie, How to remove the node_modules ? Again how to generate ? Can you provide the CLI commands please.

Comment: remove node_modules folder, and run `npm i` from the root of the project.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it in my case by removing the import.

`MatTableDataSource` is not a module. Importing just `MatTableModule` was enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add below specific configuration in package.json and npm install.

```
{ "scripts": { "postinstall": "ngcc" } }
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/ivy#speeding-up-ngcc-compilation

Comment: Applied. But still facing the same.